# Apache Struts 1.x non vulnerability version

Tags: struts1

We have a project that was developed using **Struts-1.2.4** version. As this version has some security vulnerabilities, we are planning to adopt a new version in 1.x only(not Struts 2 as Struts 2 is a complete new stuff). What's the version in Struts 1.x which has no security vulnerabilities and best one to go with?

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

If you check the vulnerability database, you will find all the 1.x versions are having few at least. Better to update to a version like 2.3.34 or never by putting some effort to the code base.

https://www.cvedetails.com/version-list/45/6117/3/Apache-Struts.html?sha=0fb43196be9e95bac47800de1a8f1497abbfb376&order=1&trc=154